# How do I solve getting 401 Unauthorized in response to attempting to obtain a token?

Tags: xamarin, identityserver4

I've got an Identity Server (using IdentityServer4), a Web API that uses the Identity Server for authorization, and a Xamarin application that is using the Identity Server to log-in and authenticate the API.

When I run all three parts locally from Visual Studio I'm able to login using the Xamarin app, obtain a token, and use that token to make API calls. However, when I publish the Identity Server to a web server (on the same network), it fails at the point that it tries to get the token. So, it shows the login page, appears to accept the login, but the POST to get the token fails with the 401 Unauthorised error in the response.

I've also configured the Identity Server to allow Swagger to connect for testing the API, and that does allow me to sign in (using Implicit) using the Identity Server installed on a Web Server.

This is the method that does the POST in the Xamarin app (mostly copied from the eShopOnContainers example):

```
public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(string uri, string data, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
  HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(string.Empty);

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
  {
      AddBasicAuthenticationHeader(httpClient, clientId, clientSecret);
  }

  var content = new StringContent(data);
  content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);

  await HandleResponse(response);
  string serialized = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  TResult result = await Task.Run(() =>
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(serialized, _serializerSettings));

  return result;
}
```

Here's the calling method for getting the token:

```
public async Task<UserToken> GetTokenAsync(string code)
{
    string data = string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&code_verifier={2}",
                                code, WebUtility.UrlEncode(Settings.Service.IdentityCallback), _codeVerifier);
    var token = await _requestProvider.PostAsync<UserToken>(
        Settings.Service.IdentityTokenEndpoint, data, Settings.Service.IdentityClientId, Settings.Service.IdentityClientSecret);
    return token;
}
```

The uri is `"http://myserver:5002/connect/token"` and headers are:

```
Accept: "application/json"
Authorization: "Basic SW5zdGVtLkFDSVMuTW9iaWxlOnNlY3JldA=="
ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

The log on the web server gives me this:

```
    info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
          Showing login: User is not authenticated
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 3.4723ms 302 
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCompany.App.Mobile%26client_secret%3Dsecret%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520app_api%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%253A5002%252FAccount%252FRedirect%26nonce%3D0dc5d79410db46739c798ce004ac89b8%26code_challenge%3DAuKmnO1hMcoEK3VeVNiVDka2U5F23HBnR0_MtxeWA3c%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26state%3D031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
          Route matched with {action = "Login", controller = "Account"}. Executing action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer)
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
          Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer) with arguments (/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=Company.App.Mobile&client_secret=secret&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20app_api%20offline_access&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver%3A5002%2FAccount%2FRedirect&nonce=0dc5d79410db46739c798ce004ac89b8&code_challenge=AuKmnO1hMcoEK3VeVNiVDka2U5F23HBnR0_MtxeWA3c&code_challenge_method=S256&state=031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016) - Validation state: Valid
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
          Executed action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 0.3611ms.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
          Executing ViewResult, running view Login.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[4]
          Executed ViewResult - view Login executed in 1.7974ms.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
          Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer) in 2.4715ms
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 3.1044ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/css/site.css  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
          The file /css/site.css was not modified
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 0.6236ms 304 text/css
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
          The file /lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js was not modified
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 0.3461ms 304 application/javascript
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/lib/jquery/jquery.js  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
          The file /lib/jquery/jquery.js was not modified
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 0.2798ms 304 application/javascript
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/icon.png  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
          The file /icon.png was not modified
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 0.2655ms 304 image/png
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
          The file /lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css was not modified
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 0.26ms 304 text/css
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://myserver:5002/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCompany.App.Mobile%26client_secret%3Dsecret%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520app_api%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%253A5002%252FAccount%252FRedirect%26nonce%3D0dc5d79410db46739c798ce004ac89b8%26code_challenge%3DAuKmnO1hMcoEK3VeVNiVDka2U5F23HBnR0_MtxeWA3c%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26state%3D031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016 application/x-www-form-urlencoded 712
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
          Route matched with {action = "Login", controller = "Account"}. Executing action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer)
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
          Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer) with arguments (IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.LoginInputModel, login) - Validation state: Valid
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
          AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
          Executed action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 1.0902ms.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
          Executing ViewResult, running view Redirect.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[4]
          Executed ViewResult - view Redirect executed in 10.0474ms.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
          Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Login (Company.IdentityServer) in 12.3805ms
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 13.1928ms 302 text/html; charset=utf-8
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=Company.App.Mobile&client_secret=secret&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20app_api%20offline_access&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver%3A5002%2FAccount%2FRedirect&nonce=0dc5d79410db46739c798ce004ac89b8&code_challenge=AuKmnO1hMcoEK3VeVNiVDka2U5F23HBnR0_MtxeWA3c&code_challenge_method=S256&state=031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016  
    info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
          Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
    info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
          ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
          {
            "ClientId": "Company.App.Mobile",
            "ClientName": "App Mobile",
            "RedirectUri": "http://myserver:5002/Account/Redirect",
            "AllowedRedirectUris": [
              "http://myserver:5002/Account/Redirect"
            ],
            "SubjectId": "eb194e4a-a2f7-482c-8c43-204567ebd591",
            "ResponseType": "code id_token",
            "ResponseMode": "fragment",
            "GrantType": "hybrid",
            "RequestedScopes": "openid profile app_api offline_access",
            "State": "031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016",
            "Nonce": "0dc5d79410db46739c798ce004ac89b8",
            "SessionId": "0ed1a950919c3b368e1249ec74e35f2c",
            "Raw": {
              "client_id": "Company.App.Mobile",
              "client_secret": "secret",
              "response_type": "code id_token",
              "scope": "openid profile app_api offline_access",
              "redirect_uri": "http://myserver:5002/Account/Redirect",
              "nonce": "0dc5d79410db46739c798ce004ac89b8",
              "code_challenge": "AuKmnO1hMcoEK3VeVNiVDka2U5F23HBnR0_MtxeWA3c",
              "code_challenge_method": "S256",
              "state": "031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016"
            }
          }
    info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
          Authorize endpoint response
          {
            "SubjectId": "eb194e4a-a2f7-482c-8c43-204567ebd591",
            "ClientId": "Company.App.Mobile",
            "RedirectUri": "http://myserver:5002/Account/Redirect",
            "State": "031db7b77c7249aebb6f7ae205dac016",
            "Scope": "openid profile app_api offline_access"
          }
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
          AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 40.3114ms 302 
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
          Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://myserver:5002/Account/Redirect  
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
          Request finished in 0.9519ms 404
```

The address `"http://myserver:5002/Account/Redirect"` doesn't actually exist because the client is a Xamarin app, so I don't think the 404 at the end is an issue. There doesn't seem to be anything in the log for the call to obtain the token.

Here's the Client config for the Identity Server:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "ACIS Mobile",
    ClientId = "Instem.ACIS.Mobile",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    RedirectUris = {$"{identityUri}/Account/Redirect"},
    RequireConsent = false,
    RequirePkce = true,
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {$"{identityUri}/Account/Redirecting"},
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://xamarinapp" },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "acis_api"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
},
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Swagger UI",
    ClientId="swaggerui",
    AllowedGrantTypes=GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser=true,
    RedirectUris = { $"{webApiUri}/oauth2-redirect.html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris={ $"{webApiUri}/" },
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "acis_api"
    }
}
```

The Identity server startup configuration is pretty simple:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration))
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
    //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    .AddSigningCredential("some certificate thumbprint", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, NameType.Thumbprint);

  services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
  {
    options.ClientId = "someclientid";
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientSecret = "somesecret";
  });
}

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

In IIS I've configured it to allow Anonymous and Basic authentication.

This is pretty much all new to me and I was making progress until this point, but I can't see any reason why it's giving me the 401 Unauthorized error, and I can't even see anything in any logs to give me anything to go on.

Edit:

I found a log file with more information:

```
2019-01-08 12:08:51 172.26.2.174 POST /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCompany.App.Mobile%26client_secret%3Dsecret%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520app_api%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%253A5002%252FAccount%252FRedirect%26nonce%3Ddc06cb800d6f4f729df03a986ff2f165%26code_challenge%3DN343zy63pcw_E75ET0HZQWGU_5ALC6H6sXt836z6mzo%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26state%3D86f26cf6a5184d9a8263aac954711819 5002 - 172.16.190.147 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+WebView/3.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/64.0.3282.140+Safari/537.36+Edge/17.17134 http://myserver:5002/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCompany.App.Mobile%26client_secret%3Dsecret%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520app_api%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%253A5002%252FAccount%252FRedirect%26nonce%3Ddc06cb800d6f4f729df03a986ff2f165%26code_challenge%3DN343zy63pcw_E75ET0HZQWGU_5ALC6H6sXt836z6mzo%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26state%3D86f26cf6a5184d9a8263aac954711819 302 0 0 156
2019-01-08 12:09:49 172.26.2.174 GET /connect/authorize/callback client_id=Company.App.Mobile&client_secret=secret&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20app_api%20offline_access&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver%3A5002%2FAccount%2FRedirect&nonce=dc06cb800d6f4f729df03a986ff2f165&code_challenge=N343zy63pcw_E75ET0HZQWGU_5ALC6H6sXt836z6mzo&code_challenge_method=S256&state=86f26cf6a5184d9a8263aac954711819 5002 - 172.16.190.147 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+WebView/3.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/64.0.3282.140+Safari/537.36+Edge/17.17134 http://myserver:5002/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCompany.App.Mobile%26client_secret%3Dsecret%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520app_api%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%253A5002%252FAccount%252FRedirect%26nonce%3Ddc06cb800d6f4f729df03a986ff2f165%26code_challenge%3DN343zy63pcw_E75ET0HZQWGU_5ALC6H6sXt836z6mzo%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26state%3D86f26cf6a5184d9a8263aac954711819 302 0 0 593
2019-01-08 12:10:33 172.26.2.174 POST /connect/token - 5002 Company.App.Mobile 172.16.190.147 - - 401 1 1326 50
2019-01-08 12:10:33 172.26.2.174 GET /Account/Redirect - 5002 - 172.16.190.147 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+WebView/3.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/64.0.3282.140+Safari/537.36+Edge/17.17134 http://myserver:5002/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCompany.App.Mobile%26client_secret%3Dsecret%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520app_api%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyserver%253A5002%252FAccount%252FRedirect%26nonce%3Ddc06cb800d6f4f729df03a986ff2f165%26code_challenge%3DN343zy63pcw_E75ET0HZQWGU_5ALC6H6sXt836z6mzo%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26state%3D86f26cf6a5184d9a8263aac954711819 404 0 0 15
```

It's the connect/token line that has the 401 error.

Comment: Just to be clear it's the call to the token endpoint that's throwing a 401? Is anything logged on the IDS4 side when that call is made?

Comment: Yes, it's the POST to the token endpoint. I've managed to find a more useful log that has some information about the error: I edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had Basic Authentication enabled in IIS for the Identity Server. Once I turned that off, it works fine.